# Known Issues about having multiple web.config files and visual studio 2005/2008 SP1

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I seem to be having a problem with my visual studio 2005/2008 installation or something because it isn't providing any `IntelliSense` whatsoever for controls registered on `web.config` files in folders different from the root, but it isn't showing any errors neither. Is this behavior normal?

I have access only to the folder of my sub-app, so I can't modify the root's `web.config` file. Well I COULD, but I'm NOT allowed to.

What I'm trying is to register some `WebUserControl`'s on the `web.config` file for my sub-app folder, so all the pages in my sub-app can use the `WebUserControl`'s without having to register them on every page, but I'm not getting `IntelliSense` for those controls registered on the `web.config` file on my sub-app folder, but I do get `IntelliSense` if I register them on the root's `web.config` file. `IntelliSense` for everything else appears to be working fine.

In the `web.config` file on my sub-app folder I have something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>       
    <system.web>
        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="qme" tagName="EmptySearchMessage" src="~/QMinerals/WebUserControls/EmptySearchMessage.ascx"/>
                <add tagPrefix="uc1" tagName="uc_general" src="~/uc_general.ascx" />
                <add tagPrefix="uc1" tagName="uc_menu" src="~/uc_menu.ascx" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

am I doing something wrong?

**Update**
Now I have upgraded to VS2008 SP1 and the issue persist

Comment: Did you have IntelliSense before in your web.config file?

Comment: Yes, I have IntelliSense working fine on everyhting else including all of Web.config files, but not on the pages. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try removing "~" from the path and using it relative to web.config? (yeah, even if works now)
- Do you have Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1?

Comment: Hi mohamed. Yes I have visual studio 2005 SP1. I'm gonna try your sugestion of relative paths and get back here to let U know if it worked.

Comment: @Mohamed. I tried your suggestion, but the issue continues. any new thoughts?

Comment: Is this a website or web application? I understand it is made as application in IIS, but also in VS (usually web app creates one DLL for all pages, website creates one DLL per page or sub folder). And how do you open the website at all? Is the sub folder the root of your VS Project or the project opens starting from the parent folder?

Comment: So sorry for the long wait, but I didn't noticed your comment. Is a website, and it opens starting from the parent folder, it is not a different project, it's just a folder in the website.